# Translate physical compute power to virtual (cloud) compute

Tags: cpu, amazon-web-services, azure, cloud

I have requirements from a software vendor that stipulate processor must be:
Dual Core 3.0 GHz/i7

The software will be deployed on the cloud (Azure/AWS).

Is there a simple way that I can 'translate' these requirements into equivalent Azure/AWS vCPU to achieve the required performance.

I'm not technical... I'm trying to establish the cost for the compute power on Azure/AWS.

Comment: For an Azure VM, you could refer to this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stephw/2015/06/01/details-of-the-azure-processors-for-vm-sizes/). Azure provides Intel Xeon E5-2670 series CPU.

Answer (score 1):

For AWS you can use the [AWS Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

1. Choose your region from the drop down
2. Under EC2 instances, click on the little nut / bolt symbol by the "type column". That gives you a chart of CPU/RAM the instance has.
3. Choose your billing option. On-demand for paying by the hour, or reserved instances if you know you'll run it for at least a year. Suggest you use on-demand to start.
4. Add disk, further down the page under EBS volumes. Include snapshot storage of say double your disk storage.

I've put together an [on-demand example](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=IAD&s=EC2&key=calc-C3CB382D-4772-4BD2-8131-8D36B9E08051) and a [reserved instance example](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=IAD&s=EC2&key=calc-8DCBBFDC-E5E2-4E39-A841-9556D739E086). This uses a t2.medium instance with 2 cores and 4GB RAM, which is suitable for moderate workloads, 30GB of disk. Both are Linux but you can easily change to Windows instances in that calculator. [t2 instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html) only get a fraction of the available CPU time, if you have a heavy workload you'll want M (general purpose) instances which have one or more cores dedicated.

On-demand: $40.52 per month, total for a year $486
1 year up-front reservation: $275 up front, $6.11 per month, total $348.

The specification from the software vendor is quite generic. Don't worry about the core type they asked for, any instance type will be fine. You could even try a cheap t2.micro to see if the application works.

Azure has a [similar calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).